# split data frame faster

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I create a function and i use the split function but it take a long time to get the result :

```
st=c(0 ,0, 9,39,44 ,100, 0, 0, 8,26 ,100, 0, 0, 6, 9,16,20,24,29,35,37,47,54,73 ,100, 0, 0, 6,35,44 ,100, 0, 0,10,16,27,40,51,91, 100, 0, 0,3, 7,28,69,71,75, 100, 0, 0,19 ,100, 0, 0, 7,24,29,35 ,100, 0, 0, 8,11,14,15,18,31,32,33,50,53,56,62,79,80,82,87,88,89, 100, 0, 0, 2,7,31,34,40 ,100, 0, 0,10,41,51,76 ,100, 0, 0, 4,32,41,46 ,100, 0, 0,19,26,59,76,83,88,92 ,100, 0, 0,11,27,51, 100, 0, 0, 5, 7,45,56,78,3 ,100, 0, 0, 3,12,23,46,53,72 ,100)

int=c(0.00,3.52 ,11.94,1.78 ,22.00,0.00,0.00,5.85 ,14.26 ,56.65,0.00,0.00,4.52,2.76,4.89,3.17,3.36,3.67,4.49,1.97,7.47,5.55, 14.79 ,20.78,0.00,0.00,4.51 ,20.71,6.60 ,40.08,0.00,0.00 ,11.28,7.30 , 12.14 ,14.01, 12.82 ,45.65,9.97,0.00,0.00,2.33,3.72 ,19.55, 37.61,1.72,3.56 ,23.05,0.00,0.00 ,13.51 ,57.64,0.00,0.00,4.74 ,11.42,3.51,4.38 ,43.83,0.00,0.00,5.66,2.35,1.62,1.09,2.05,8.76,0.63,1.05, 11.65,2.34,1.82,4.78, 11.41,1.10,1.52,3.41,0.61,1.01,7.41,0.00,0.00,2.09,3.72,21.57,2.69,5.65 ,53.43,0.00,0.00,3.77 ,12.05,3.85,9.88,9.13,0.00,0.00,3.32 ,20.97,6.61,3.47 ,40.62,0.00,0.00,3.26,1.27,5.71,2.94,1.13,0.89,0.78,1.31,0.00,0.00,4.91,7.03 ,10.14 ,21.36,0.00,0.00,4.16,2.22 ,33.84 ,10.72, 19.17 ,13.68,6.49,0.00,0.00,1.83,5.22,6.95, 13.92,4.04, 11.66 ,17.04,0.00)

id=c(1:length(st))

Attr=c("sta","a",  "cr","a",  "hf", "sp", "sta","hf", "cr",
       "a",  "sp", "sta","a",  "ac","a",  "hf" ,"cr","a",
       "ac","a",  "sl", "cr","a",  "pq","sp", "sta","a",
       "sl", "cr","hf" ,"sp", "sta","a",  "cr","sl", "hf",
       "a",  "pq","hf", "sp", "sta","cr","a",  "hf", "sl",
       "cr","hf" ,"a",  "sp", "sta","hf" ,"cr","sp", "sta",
       "hc","cr","hf", "sl", "a",  "sp", "sta","hf", "a",
       "cr","hf" ,"a",  "cr","hf", "a",  "cr","hf", "a",
       "hf", "cr","hf" ,"a",  "cr","hf", "a",  "cr","sp",
       "sta","cr","a",  "hf", "a",  "cr","hf" ,"sp", "sta",
       "sl", "a",  "hf" ,"cr","a",  "sp", "sta","a",  "ac",
       "sl", "hf" ,"cr","sp", "sta","hc","pv","a",  "hf",
       "a",  "pv","hc","sl", "sp", "sta","hf", "a",  "cr",
       "sl", "sp", "sta","hf", "a",  "cr","a",  "a",  "sl",
       "a",  "sp", "sta","cr","hf" ,"a",  "sl", "cr","a","hf" ,"sp")
p=replicate(length(Attr),sample(1:3,1,replace=T))
data=cbind.data.frame(id,st,int,Attr,p) 


 si<-function(data,...){
    ff<-list()
    library(MASS)
    library(Hmisc)
    att<-function(data,...){
      d=data
      f=list()
      z=list()

      f=split(data, data$Attr,drop=T)
      z=lapply(f,function(x){if(nrow(x)> 1){fitdistr(as.integer(x$int),"Negative Binomial")}})
      z=z[!sapply(z, is.null)]
      return(z)
    }
    data$p=as.factor(data$p)

    datap=list()
    d=list()
    s=list()
      for(i in 1:3){
        datap[[i]]=data[data$p==i,]
        d[[i]]=subset(datap[[i]],int != 0)
      }

    s=lapply(d,att)

    return(s)
  }
```

and I have to use this function 4000 time :

```
system.time(a<-replicate(4000,si(data)))
utilisateur     système      écoulé 
     110.02        1.01      111.33
```

So my question is if there is any other alternative to split data faster and speed up the function execution time

Comment: Have you profiled your function to see what actually takes so long?

Comment: yes and i think the l apply function take so long and after that the split

Comment: I've profiled it and it seems that `fitdistr` is taking the longest time, not split: https://github.com/privefl/mySO/blob/master/profiler1.png.

Comment: The profiling I was referring to is something as described here: https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/ (if you're using RStudio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function was too complicated, I simplified it a bit but it didn't gain much time. Like others have said, the largest share of time spent goes to `fitdistr`, then `densfun`, then `.Call`. And those are all in the call to `fitdistr`, so cannot be optimized. (I used the profiling code by Federico Manigrasso.)
First of all I put the `library`calls at the beginning of the code, not inside the function. I also changed the way you create the `data.frame`.

```
library(MASS)
library(Hmisc)

data <- data.frame(id,st,int,Attr,p) 

si2 <- function(data,...){
    att<-function(data,...){
      z=lapply(split(data, data$Attr,drop=T), function(x){
          if(nrow(x)> 1) fitdistr(as.integer(x$int),"Negative Binomial")
      })
      z[!sapply(z, is.null)]
    }

    inx <- data$int != 0
    lapply(lapply(1:3, function(i) data[data$p==i & inx,]), att)
}

system.time(a<-replicate(4000,si(data)))
   user  system elapsed 
  89.40    0.00   89.73 
system.time(b<-replicate(4000,si2(data)))
   user  system elapsed 
  84.21    0.03   84.33 
identical(a, b)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi try this  to profile your code

```
Rprof(interval = 0.0001)
si(data)
Rprof(NULL)
siprof <- summaryRprof()$by.self
siprof$Fun <- rownames(siprof)
head(siprof)
head(siprof[order(siprof$self.time, decreasing = TRUE),])
sum(siprof$self.time)
```

In my case what takes time is the loading of the library in fact the first time I run the code

```
sum(siprof$self.time)  was equal to  29.276

the second time 
sum(siprof$self.time)  was equal to  3.368
```

you can see also different function in head(siprof), the function that takes longer are related to the attachmment of the library

the first time

```
    self.time self.pct total.time total.pct               Fun
"lazyLoadDBfetch"     5.333    18.21      5.562     18.99 "lazyLoadDBfetch"
"gzfile"              2.108     7.20      2.121      7.24          "gzfile"
".getGeneric"         1.451     4.96      1.994      6.81     ".getGeneric"
"getClassDef"         1.133     3.87      2.024      6.91     "getClassDef"
"file.exists"         1.126     3.85      1.176      4.02     "file.exists"
"FUN"                 0.863     2.95      5.513     18.83             "FUN"
```

the second time

```
  self.time self.pct total.time total.pct             Fun
"parse"             0.326     9.67      0.486     14.41         "parse"
"fitdistr"          0.250     7.41      1.905     56.54      "fitdistr"
"print.default"     0.173     5.13      0.173      5.13 "print.default"
"paste"             0.160     4.75      0.193      5.74         "paste"
"densfun"           0.135     4.00      0.227      6.73       "densfun"
"match"             0.110     3.26      0.126      3.73         "match"
```

PS use

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(a<-si(data),times=4000)
```

to evaluate better your expression

So at the end of the day, yout code could be improve maybe from a stylistic point of view, but there is no much to gain in term of computational time